# backside selected only by border select and lasso, but not mouse click

Tags: python, scripting, interface, 3d-view

I would want that backside selected only by border select  and lasso, but not mouse click. 
I would like that mouse click does not select backside faces. Only lasso and border selection would do it. Is it possible to do?
[image]

Comment: For the first question; I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i guess he means how to see the cage and don't select backfaces. First question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without some major tricks (python or editing C source)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the basic idea : we keep the occluding OFF but switch it ON only when selecting with mouse click, and for this you create your own operator for selection and replace the shortcuts to point to this new operator.( or simply override the old operator )

Here is the code that does that run it then set the shortcuts

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, IntVectorProperty

class SelectionOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ Costum selection
    """
    bl_idname = "view3d.select_costum" #to override the old selection replace this with "view3d.select"
    bl_label = "costum selection"

    extend = BoolProperty(default = False)
    deselect = BoolProperty(default = False)
    toggle = BoolProperty(default = False)
    center = BoolProperty(default = False)
    enumerate = BoolProperty(default = False)
    object = BoolProperty(default = False)
    location = IntVectorProperty(default = (0,0),subtype ='XYZ', size = 2)

    def execute(self, context):
        context.space_data.use_occlude_geometry = True
        bpy.ops.view3d.select(extend=self.extend, deselect=self.deselect, toggle=self.toggle, center=self.center, enumerate=self.enumerate, object=self.object, location=(self.location[0] , self.location[1] ))
        context.space_data.use_occlude_geometry = False    
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.space_data.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            self.location[0] = event.mouse_region_x
            self.location[1]  = event.mouse_region_y
            return self.execute(context)
        else:
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "Active space must be a View3d")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(SelectionOperator)
```

if you didn't override the old selection you have to change the shortcuts :

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- in **Input**➝3D view➝3D view Global➝Activate/Select
- change the operator to ***view3d.select_costum***
- repeat for all the ***Activate/Select*** entries below this one

[image]

Comment: If I wish to override the original selection operator (e.g. for an addon), where can I store the original operator to still be able to call it from the new custom selection tool (as running `bpy.ops.view3d.select()` will cause an infinite loop)?

Comment: @Banana overriding seems to crash blender ( at least mine ) so it's not the way to go  , but i have done a shortcut replacement  which is safer and can be reversed